# gfortran, DLL and nothing making sense (or working) at all

Tags: dll, fortran, gfortran

I have the following short piece of code in Fortran, which I named myDLL.f90:

```
    Real(Kind=8) Function mySinCos(x,y)
        Real(Kind=8), Intent(In) :: x, y

        mySinCos = Sin(x)*Cos(y)
    End Function mySinCos

    Real(Kind=8) Function myPiSinCos(x,y)
        Real(Kind=8), Intent(In) :: x, y
        Real(Kind=8), Parameter :: Pi = 4.0d0*Datan(1.0d0)

        myPiSinCos = Sin(Pi*x)*Cos(Pi*y)
    End Function myPiSinCos
```

And the following main program TestDLL.f90:

```
    Program TestDLL

        Real(Kind=8) :: x, y
        Real(Kind=8) :: a, b

        x = 2.0d-01
        y = 9.0d-01

        a = mySinCos(x,y)       !Should be 0.12349483641187213
        b = myPiSinCos(x,y)     !Should be -0.5590169943749475

        Write(*,*) a
        Write(*,*) b

    End Program TestDLL
```

I compiled and linked the above sources with:

gfortran -shared -fPIC -o myDLL.dll myDLL.f90

gfortran -o a.exe TestDLL.f90 -L. myDLL.dll

No compilation/linkedition errors and **a.exe** runs without error messages. What it produces is:

```
   6.0000000000000000
   6.0000000000000000
```

Which obviously aren't the expected results as **sin(...)*cos(...)** must never be > 0.5 (or < -0.5), let alone 6.0000[...].

In a nutshell: compiled well, linked well, executed well and produced garbage.

Changing either *x* or *y* doesn't change the results. They're always 6.0000[...].

What went wrong? The example above doesn't differ a lot from other simple examples I've found in the internet.

I'm using GNU Fortran (MinGW.org GCC Build-20200227-1) 9.2.0, Windows 10 64-bit.

Comment: Please add `implicit none` to your program and see that you haven't declared the return type of `mySinCos` or `myPiSinCos`.

Comment: @francescalus The `Implicit None` did the magic. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

It works fine if I turn the two functions into a module:

```
    Module myDLL

        Implicit None

        Contains

        ... The two original functions are inserted here ...

    End Module myDLL
```

and import/use the module in the main program:

```
    Program TestDLL

        Use myDLL

        Implicit None

        ... Other commands are inserted here ...

    End Program TestDLL
```

Then, and only then, the correct results are spit.